# Setting up apple-app-site-association for Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff (iOS 8)

Tags: objective-c, openssl, certificate, handoff, ios8-handoff

I'm a newbie to certificates and openssl.

I want to understand how to sign a JSON file using  openssl command with the **certificate and key for an identity** issued by a certificate authority trusted by iOS.

How to get certificate and key for my identity? Is it like how XCode signs my app for distribution?

Kindly help me to understand!

Link for apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10

Comment: Its not clear to me what *"Setting up Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff"* means. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: Check the documentation he/she posted. I'm in a similar boat here. I can't seem to figure out which combination of keys/certs they want to get this JSON file signed correctly. They very poorly explain the command in the "Adopting Handoff" document.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate and key you need here is unrelated to the certificate and keys used in XCode to sign and distribute your application. In the case of signing this JSON file, the key and certificate refers to the ones used to verify your ownership of a particular web domain. This is typically used when securing your web domain with TSL/SSL for 'https' access. These are typically called "SSL certificates". You can obtain them directly from SSL certificate providers (google it) or via the domain registrar where you purchased your web domain.

Comment: The list of trusted CA was not very clear in the support doc. Is there any free signing available from trusted CA's?

Comment: I think you can expect the list of trusted CAs to be comparable to those of most operating systems and web browsers out there. In these cases I am not sure where to obtain free SSL certificates. I mostly use namecheap which provides Comodo certificates for $9. It is probably good practice to secure your website with https anyway and wouldn't view it as strictly a cost to making handoff work.

Answer (score -3):

You can see [this](http://techlife.cookpad.com/entry/2014/12/11/093000) tutorial for setting up the association file.
The most important thing is you must use the iPhone distribution certificate to sign your JSON file.